# How can I restrict users with 64 bit devices to install my iOS app?

Tags: ios, 64-bit

I am working on an iPhone app that uses a framework that only works with 64-bit devices.

Other than targeting iOS 11, How can I restrict my app to work with only 64-bit iOS devices?

Comment: Have you tried removing 32bit architectures from Build Settings?

Comment: hi, not yet, but my question is if that change will disable the app showing on appstore for 32 bit device? thanks

Comment: Supported devices shown on the AppStore are stored in your app's Info.plist file under `UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities` item. If you change that, your supported devices on the AppStore will change as well :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48285965/using-uirequireddevicecapabilities-in-info-plist-to-limit-compatible-devices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Build setting and set below parameters

```
1. Valid Architectures = arm64
2. Build Active Architecture Only  
           Debug = NO            // This setting is for simulator to work
           Release = Yes         // This is for device
```